# How to asynchronously load a google map in AngularJS?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, asynchronous, angularjs, lazy-loading, angularjs-directive

Now that I have found a way to initialize Google Maps with the help of [Andy Joslin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1397051/andy-joslin) in this SO [initialize-google-map-in-angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180750/initialize-google-map-in-angularjs), I am looking for a way to asynchronous load a Google Map Object.

I found an example of how to do this in the [phonecat](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat) project.

Notice how the JS files are loaded in this example: [index-async.html](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/00a07064623f1c0df7e03c5e38aa976695b5c899/app/index-async.html)

In my Jade Scripts partial that is loaded into my program I tried:

```
script(src='js/lib/angular/angular.js')
script(src='js/lib/script/script.min.js')

script
  $script([
    'js/lib/angular/angular-resource.min.js',
    'js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js',
    'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBTmi_pcXMZtLX5MWFRQgbVEYx-h-pDXO4&sensor=false',
    'js/app.js',
    'js/services.js',
    'js/controllers.js',
    'js/filters.js',
    'js/directives.js',
    'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'
    ], function() {
      // when all is done, execute bootstrap angular application
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['ofm']);
    });
```

When I do this and go to load the map page I get:

```
A call to document.write() from an asycrononously-loaded 
external script was ignored.
```

This is how Google Maps is being loaded now as a service:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('ofm.services', []);

app.factory('GoogleMaps', function() {

  var map_id  = '#map';
  var lat     = 46.87916;
  var lng     = -3.32910;
  var zoom    = 15;
  var map     = initialize(map_id, lat, lng, zoom);

  return map;
});

function initialize(map_id, lat, lng, zoom) {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom : 8,
    center : new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  return new google.maps.Map($(map_id)[0], myOptions);
}
```

It appears that this should be returning a promise from what I recall reading. But this AngularJS is very new to me.

Comment: To promote progress on this I created a git project here: https://github.com/LarryEitel/angular-google-maps AND pushed it live here: http://angular-google-maps.nodester.com/. I started a thread in Google Groups on this here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&nomobile=true#!topic/angular/CM8ewcWeTF4

Comment: When you load the Maps API library asynchronously, you *must* provide a callback function with the `callback=` query parameter. Otherwise the API loader will use `document.write()` which doesn't work from an asynchronous call. The mini-library in [GFoley83](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17396353/1202830)'s answer adds this parameter for you, which is why it can work in an asynchronous loading situation like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you using jQuery in your AngularJS app, check out this function which returns a `promise` for when the Google Maps API has been loaded:

https://gist.github.com/gbakernet/828536

I was able to use this in a AngularJS directive to lazy-load Google Maps on demand. 
Works a treat:

```
angular.module('mapModule') // usage: data-google-map
    .directive('googleMap', ['$window', function ($window) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                // If Google maps is already present then just initialise my map
                if ($window.google && $window.google.maps) {
                    initGoogleMaps();
                } else {
                    loadGoogleMapsAsync();
                }

                function loadGoogleMapsAsync() {
                    // loadGoogleMaps() == jQuery function from https://gist.github.com/gbakernet/828536
                    $.when(loadGoogleMaps())
                        // When Google maps is loaded, add InfoBox - this is optional
                        .then(function () {
                            $.ajax({ url: "/resources/js/infobox.min.js", dataType: "script", async: false });
                        })
                        .done(function () {
                            initGoogleMaps();
                        });
                };

                function initGoogleMaps() {
                    // Load your Google map stuff here
                    // Remember to wrap scope variables inside `scope.$apply(function(){...});`
                }
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: Eek, mixed Angular and jQuery!

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Bet your ass I did! Currently there's no easy way to load scripts with AngularJS and the Google Maps API doesn't support promises natively. I've proposed a more than adequate solution; if you've got a better one then lets see it! :)

Comment: GFoley, I take your point and I didn't say this wasn't rational, I just said "eek". I've not tried but can AngularJS's $q not coerce jQuery promises into its own as per Q.js? If so, then in `loadGoogleMapsAsync()`, all but the `$.ajax(...)` expression can be written with $q, which seems more appropriate in an Angular.js module.

Comment: Also, should you not `return $ajax(...)`? Otherwise (a) `initGoogleMaps()` might as well be inside the `.then()` callback, and (b) the user could start interacting with the map before `infobox` is available.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I've not used `$q` at all as I'm still new to Angular though I'd imagine you could easily switch it out, yeah. Feel free to update my answer above if you find a working solution. As for your a & b, that's getting off topic.

Comment: I'll see if I can find time to run some tests with $q.

Answer (score 7):

here's my solution I came up without using jQuery:
([Gist here](https://gist.github.com/neilsoult/7255583))

```
angular.module('testApp', []).
    directive('lazyLoad', ['$window', '$q', function ($window, $q) {
        function load_script() {
            var s = document.createElement('script'); // use global document since Angular's $document is weak
            s.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize';
            document.body.appendChild(s);
        }
        function lazyLoadApi(key) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $window.initialize = function () {
                deferred.resolve();
            };
            // thanks to Emil Stenström: http://friendlybit.com/js/lazy-loading-asyncronous-javascript/
            if ($window.attachEvent) {  
                $window.attachEvent('onload', load_script); 
            } else {
                $window.addEventListener('load', load_script, false);
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) { // function content is optional
            // in this example, it shows how and when the promises are resolved
                if ($window.google && $window.google.maps) {
                    console.log('gmaps already loaded');
                } else {
                    lazyLoadApi().then(function () {
                        console.log('promise resolved');
                        if ($window.google && $window.google.maps) {
                            console.log('gmaps loaded');
                        } else {
                            console.log('gmaps not loaded');
                        }
                    }, function () {
                        console.log('promise rejected');
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look of this i think its more reliable

```
    var deferred = $q.defer();
                        var script = document.createElement('script');

                        $window.initMap = function() {
                            //console.log("Map  init ");

                            deferred.resolve();
                        }
                        script.src = "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places&callback=initMap";
                        document.body.appendChild(script);
                        return deferred.promise;
```