# Google map doesn't show on second partial view with angularjs

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angularjs

I've been following the answers/examples in this question here.
[Initialize Google Map in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180750/initialize-google-map-in-angularjs)

I've setup a plunker example of whats happening.  http://plnkr.co/edit/5fN7PR

Including the git repo example.  My map loads when I first view the map page (partial) however if I select another link then go back to the map the map doesn't load.  I can see the map still exists as its being called its just not replacing the div with id="map".

I don't care that the map will be reinitialized at this stage, I've setup a store for the maps for different places, however that won't work without the map!  My list and details pages work as expected.  /web/place is a ajax call to my silex backend.

### index.html

```
<div class="container full-width" ng-view></div>
```

### app.js

```
'use strict';

/* App Module */
var app = angular.module('places', ['Controllers', 'Filters', 'Services']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/places', {templateUrl: 'partials/place-list.html',   controller: 'ListController'}).
      when('/places/:placeId/details', {templateUrl: 'partials/place-detail.html', controller: 'DetailController'}).
      when('/places/:placeId/map', {templateUrl: 'partials/place-map.html', controller: 'MapController'}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/places'});
}]);
```

### controllers.js

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */
var controllers;
controllers = angular.module("Controllers", []);

controllers.controller("ListController", function($scope, Place) {
    $scope.places = Place.query();
});

controllers.controller("DetailController", function($scope, $routeParams, Place) {
    $scope.place = Place.get({placeId: $routeParams.placeId});
});

controllers.controller("MapController", function($scope, $routeParams, Place, GoogleMaps) {
    $scope.place = Place.get({placeId: $routeParams.placeId});
    $scope.map = GoogleMaps;
});
```

### services.js

```
'use strict';

/* Services */
var services;

services = angular.module('Services', ['ngResource']);

services.factory('Place', function($resource){
    return $resource('/web/place/:placeId', {}, {
        query: {method:'GET', params:{placeId:'list'}, isArray:true}
    });
});


services.factory('GoogleMaps', function() {
    var map_id  = '#map';
    var lat     = -25;
    var lng     = 133;
    var zoom    = 16;
    var map     = initialize(map_id, lat, lng, zoom);

    console.log(map);
    return map;

    function initialize(map_id, lat, lng, zoom) {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom : zoom,
            center : new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        console.log(myOptions);

        return new google.maps.Map($(map_id)[0], myOptions);
    }
});
```

### place-map.html

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this code this reload the map each time the partial view is loaded.  This isn't happening!

Comment: I've started using angularjs UI.  It has solved my problem.

Comment: Consider deleting this question or adding your comment as an answer, so that this question no longer appears on the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've started using angularjs UI. It has solved my problem.