# Google MAP API Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use Google MAP API v3 with the following code.

```
<h2>Topology</h2>

<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% url css_media 'tooltip.topology.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% url css_media 'tooltip.css' %}" />

<style type="text/css" >
      #map_canvas {
              width:300px;
            height:300px;
     }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var myOptions = {
zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);

</script>

<div id="map_canvas"> </div>
```

When I run this code, the browser says this.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

I have no idea, since I follow the direction given in [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).

Do you have any clue?

Answer (score 324, accepted):

This problem is usually due to the map div not being rendered before the javascript runs that needs to access it.

You should put your initialization code inside an onload function or at the bottom of your HTML file, just before the  tag, so the DOM is completely rendered before it executes (note that the second option is more sensitive to invalid HTML).

Note, as pointed out by [matthewsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1963978/matthewsheets) this also could be cause by the div with that id not existing at all in your HTML (the pathological case of the div not being rendered)

Adding code sample from [wf9a5m75](https://stackoverflow.com/users/697856/wf9a5m75)'s post to put everything in one place:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

</script>
```

Comment: This happens to me all the time when I forget to conditionalize my maps script. Adding: var mapExists = document.getElementById("map-canvas"); if(mapExists) { // script } makes it all better.

Answer (score 109):

**For others that might still be having this issue**, even after trying the above recommendations, using an incorrect selector for your map canvas in the initialize function can cause this same issue as the function is trying to access something that doesn't exist. Double-check that your map Id matches in your initialize function and your HTML or this same error may be thrown.

In other words, make sure your IDs match up. ;)

Comment: Amazing how you can be so sure this isn’t the problem… till you double check and realize you changed it earlier testing and forgot to change it back. :-)

Answer (score 42):

You can also get this error if you don't specify `center` or `zoom` in your map options.

Comment: That was the one!  Removed zoom from the options since I was setting it later in the script anyway, and boom, the map would load the first time, but the second time would generate that error.  Thank you!!

Comment: Yup, this was mine! Had a zoom but no center. Just adding the center fixed it.

Comment: They could've logged some message in the console at least, really. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

google uses `id="map_canvas"` and `id="map-canvas"` in the samples, double-check and re-double-check the id :D

Answer (score 23):

Year, geocodezip's answer is correct.
So change your code like this:
 (if you still in trouble, or maybe somebody else in the future)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

</script>
```

Comment: Exactly, first render the html div and then the JS else add an event listener.

Answer (score 11):

Just so I add my fail scenario in getting this to work. I had a `<div id="map>` in which I was loading the map with:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
```

and the div was initially **hidden** and it didn't have explicitly width and height values set so it's size was `width x 0`. Once I've set the size of this div in CSS like this

```
#map {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

everything worked! Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This was exactly the reason why it didn't work for me.  You need to make sure the CSS matches your map id and that you have some kind of initial width/height combo otherwise nothing is rendered.  So to recap:  1. make sure your html div id matches the id selector when you call getElementById in your JavaScript 2. make sure the CSS has code to style your particular map e.g. #map1 { width: 200px; height: 200px; } or similar so it renders.

Answer (score 7):

**For even more others that might still be having this issue,** I was using a self-closing `<div id="map1" />` tag, and the second div was not showing, and did not seem to be in the dom. as soon as i changed it to two open&close tags `<div id="map1"></div>` it worked. hth

Answer (score 6):

I had single quotes in my

```
var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map_canvas') );
```

and replaced them with double quotes

```
var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("map_canvas") );
```

This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 6):

Also take care not to write

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", init())
```

correct:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", init)
```

Comment: Indeed. That was a problem in my case too. The first one runs the init function straight away when the second one just passes init function as a parameter to event listener which will run the init function when that event occurs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286233/javascript-pass-function-as-parameter

Answer (score 5):

Changing the ID (in all 3 places) from "map-canvas" to "map" fixed it for me, even though I had made sure the IDs were the same, the div had a width and height, and the code wasn't running until after the window load call. It's not the dash; it doesn't seem to work with any other ID than "map".

Answer (score 4):

Also, make sure you're not placing hash symbol (#) inside your selector in a

```
    document.getElementById('#map') // bad

    document.getElementById('map') // good
```

statement. It's not a jQuery. Just a quick reminder for someone in a hurry.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue but the problem was that zoom was not defined within the options object given to Google Maps.

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating multiple maps in a loop, if a single map DOM element doesn't exist, it breaks all of them. First, check to make sure the DOM element exists before creating a new Map object.

```
[...]

for( var i = 0; i <= self.multiple_maps; i++ ) {

  var map_element = document.getElementById( 'map' + '-' + i.toString() );

  // Element doesn't exist, don't create map!
  if( null === map_element ) {
    continue;
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map( map_element, myOptions);
}

[...]
```

Comment: But all that does is stop the map being created, not actually fixing the mess and creating the map.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be using asp.net Webforms and are registering the script in the code behind of a page using a master page, don't forget to use the clientID of the map element (vb.net):

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "Google Maps Initialization", String.Format("init_map(""" & map_canvas.ClientID() & """...
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve it you need to add `async defer` to the script.

It should be like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

See [here](http://peter.sh/experiments/asynchronous-and-deferred-javascript-execution-explained/) the meaning of async defer.

Since you'll be calling a function from the main js file, you also want to make sure that this  is after the one where you load the main script.

Answer (score 1):

- Setup ng-init=init() in your HTML
- And in the controller

  use $scope.init = function() {...}
  instead of google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", init){...}

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include the Places library `&libraries=places` parameter when you first load the API.

For example:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, just wanted to add that the error can also happen when the div doesn't exist in the page. You can also check if the div exists first before loading the google maps function call. Something like

```
function initMap() {
    if($("#venuemap").length != 0) {
        var city= {lat: -26.2041, lng: 28.0473};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('venuemap'), {
       etc etc
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually easiest way to fix this is just move your object before Javascript code it worked to me. I guess in your answer object is loaded after javascript code.

```
<style type="text/css" >
      #map_canvas {
              width:300px;
            height:300px;
     }

 <div id="map_canvas"> </div> // Here 

<script type="text/javascript">

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var myOptions = {
zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);

</script>

<div id="map_canvas"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case these sort of issues were solved using `defer` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

`<script src="<your file>.js" defer></script>`

You need to take into account browsers's support of this option though (I haven't seen problems)

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're not overriding `window.self`

My issue: I had created a component and wrote `self = this` instead of var `self = this`. If you don't use the keyword `var`, JS will put that variable on the window object, so I overwrote `window.self` which caused this error.

Answer (score 0):

This is an edit of a previously deleted post to contain the content of the linked answer, in the answer itself. The purpose for re-publishing this answer is to function as a PSA for React 0.9+ users who have also stumbled into this issue.

## original edited post

---

Also got this error while using ReactJS while following [this blog post](http://infinitemonkeys.influitive.com/little-framework-big-splash/). sahat's comment [here](https://gist.github.com/maedhr/8823168) helped -
 see the content of sahat's comment below.

> ❗️ Note for React >= 0.9
>
> Prior to v0.9, the DOM node was passed in as the last argument. If you were using this, you can still access the DOM node by calling this.getDOMNode().
>
> In other words, replace rootNode parameter with this.getDOMNode() in the latest version of React.

Answer (score 0):

My fail was to use

```
zoomLevel
```

as an option, rather than the correct option

```
zoom
```

Answer (score 0):

add async defer at the begining of map api key call.

Answer (score 0):

In a case I was dealing with, the map div was conditionally rendered depending if the location was being made public. If you can't be sure whether the map canvas div will be on the page, simply check that your `document.getElementById` is returning an element and only invoke the map if it's present:

```
var mapEle = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
if (mapEle) {
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapEle, myOptions);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here the problem was the API link without the `key` param:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=YOURKEY"></script>
```

That way works fine.