# Google geocoding API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to learn how to use the Google geocoding API but I cannot seem to make even the simplest example produce a map. I have searched on Google for alternative tutorials but everything seems in order.

Obviously I must be missing something. Here is what I have so far :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=thisstuffisprivate&sensor=false">
        </script>
        <script>
            var map;
            var mapOptions;
            function initialize() {
                try {
                    document.write("Initialize entered");
                    mapOptions = {
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                        zoom: 8,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                    document.write("<br>Map options created");
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
                    document.write("<br>Initialize exited");
                } catch (err) {
                    document.write("<br>Error: " + err.message);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px;height:300px;">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This produces a blank page. Note that I using this code on my computer and checking the results with Firefox. This is not hosted on an external server yet.

Can anybody help me figure out what mistake I have made ? This will enable me to continue learning how to use this API !

Thank you so much !

Edit: 
- I have made a small test adding writes at the beginning and at the end of `initialize()` and it seems that it does not reach the last line (after the map creation) so it must be failing somewhere. Will try to investigate that.

- Modified to take into account width and height. Thanks to Leftium.
- After further testing, it seems to fail on the map creation step.
- The code does not work on my computer on either IE, Firefox or Chrome but seems to work for other users. I am using Windows 8 and a relatively recent version of all browsers. Javascript IS enabled and I have tried turning off Windows Defender (just in case..). Still only a blank page.
- I have also used an API key but it still produces a blank page.
- I get the following output for the updated code above:

`Initialize entered 
Map options created 
Error: a is null`

- It also produces a blank page on my Windows 7 laptop so it's not an issue of compatibility with Windows 8.

Comment: [Working Here](http://jsbin.com/oxasaz/1/edit).

Comment: What could be wrong on my computer then ? It did not work on IE, Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Is the Google maps JS file loading properly? What do you see if you put this in your address bar: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false?

Comment: I see a big chunk of JS code.

Comment: "a is null" seems like a common problem, but I couldn't find any obvious solutions. (https://www.google.com/search?q=google+maps+"a+is+null") It usually occurs when the target div for the map canvas does not exist/is not visible. Double check that your two "map_canvas" id strings really match (in JavaScript & in HTML). Were there some non-displayable characters inadvertently copy-pasted?

Comment: You're actually right. I have posted the answer I have found to solve my problem below a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With further testing I found the exact error message and a solution on another SO question. Essentially, the problem is that the div is actually not fully built and the initialize() call searches for this element before it is in the DOM (please forgive me if the nomenclature is wrong).

The solution is to move the call lower below creating the div.

[Google MAP API Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740663/google-map-api-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-offsetwidth-of-null)

Comment: I find it odd that using the <body> tag's 'onLoad' property does not prevent the missing map div problem. And why would it only affect the OP's page while working fine in JavaScript sandbox sites and other people's computers?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the "map_canvas" <div> dimensions:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px;height:300px">
```

Comment: I'm sorry I should have included it in my OP but I had this at first and tried removing it because it produced a blank page too. I modified my code to yours and it still produces a blank page :\

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur: hmm.. works for me in both Firefox and Chrome http://snag.gy/7yVdT.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Google API keys are assigned by domain name, which is in turn checked via the `HTTP_REFERER` header.  When you test on your local machine, your requests *will not* match the live domain you registered your key for (they'll say `localhost` or something).

1. You can sign up for a `http://localhost` key and use that during localhost testing.
2. OR -- You can spoof the `HTTP_REFERER` to look like it's coming from your website.  I do not know if the Google License agreement allows for this kind fo spoofing.

Comment: I do not have a website yet (no domain, no hosting) so I want to use local hosting. I have tried using a "key for server apps" but the result is the same. I have tried both letting the IP field blank or using my machine ip (both my local IP known to my router and my public IP). In all cases I still have a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to [obtain an api key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key).  There may be a limit to the number of requests an anonymous user can make, which would explain why everyone else but you is able to load the map with your example above.

You'll need to change your script tag like so:

```
  <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
  </script>
```

[Loading the map api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API)

Comment: I already have an API key (I have even re-generated it just in case). I used the URL above because it did not work with the API key and I wanted to try anonymous instead.

Comment: Understood.  Does it at least appear when you run it from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YRRHQ/)?

Comment: Yup it does appear just fine.