# Google Maps Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Since I started making my application there has always been the message in Console,  in Chrome,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Fa' of undefined
```

But seeing as my app loaded ok and I could see everything on screen, in Chrome and in Firefox, I just ignored it. I know it's related to my Google maps because when I debug for more details in Chrome I can find:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Fa' of undefined
b.b
ag.(anonymous function).Y                           %7Bmain,places%7D.js:26
tJ.(anonymous function).Yc
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)                                %7Bmain,places%7D.js:10
uJ
a.b
ag.(anonymous function).Y                           %7Bmain,places%7D.js:26
(anonymous function)
```

And the %7Bmain links go to https://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/13/6/%7Bmain,places%7D.js, which is google stuff.

However yesterday I tried my app in IE and it broke with the same error - the map wouldn't load. Any idea what could be wrong and how I can fix it?

Here's my function:

```
function initialize_google_maps() {

    var user_longitude = $("#user-position").attr("data-lng");
    var user_latitude = $("#user-position").attr("data-lat");

    var currentlatlng =
        new google.maps.LatLng(user_latitude, user_longitude);

    var zoom = 10;
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: zoom,
      center: currentlatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        streetViewControl: false,
        minZoom: 1, 
        // don't want people to be able to hone in
        // on others' addresses too specifically.
        maxZoom: 13
      };


      var map = new google.maps.Map(
          document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
          myOptions
      );

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: currentlatlng,
          icon: { opacity: 0 }
      });

      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map,
        fillOpacity: 0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        strokeOpacity: 0.7,
        radius: 10000,
      });
      circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
    }
```

I call it like this:

```
<!-- draw the map, on the right of the screen -->
    <div id="map_canvas">

      <script>
      $(function() {

// this function can be found in draw_map.js
      initialize_google_maps();

                   });
      </script>

    </div>
```

I saw a stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740663/google-map-api-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-offsetwidth-of-null) which looked similar which said make sure the javascript is loaded before the page is rendered so I tried calling my function like this:

```
      <script>
$(document).on("ready", function(){

// this function can be found in draw_map.js
      initialize_google_maps();


  });
```

but still getting the same error.

The Google maps library I'm calling like:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error I see is that you're passing *strings* into `new google.maps.LatLng()`. You need to give it numbers.

Instead of this code:

```
var user_longitude = $("#user-position").attr("data-lng");
var user_latitude = $("#user-position").attr("data-lat");

var currentlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(user_latitude, user_longitude);
```

use:

```
var $position = $("#user-position"),
    lat = $position.attr("data-lat"),
    lng = $position.attr("data-lng");

var currentlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( +lat, +lng );
```

Let me take a look through the rest of your code, but that's one thing to fix right away.

BTW just as a stylistic suggestion, as you can see I prefer shorter names in localized code like this. Since the data attributes are `data-lat` and `data-lng` and the Maps API function is called `LatLng`, there's little to be gained by spelling out `user_latitude` and `user_longitude` in this bit of code. `lat` and `lng` are pretty standard terms in Maps API code.

The second problem is an invalid `icon` object in this code:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: currentlatlng,
    icon: { opacity: 0 }
});
```

An `icon` object needs a `url`, and there's no such thing as an `opacity` option. If you remove the `icon: { opacity: 0 }` and fix the lat/lng problem then the map will load without error.

If you want a marker with no icon, one way to do it is with a transparent PNG file. You can download a copy of this file to your server:

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/1x1.png
```

and then change this line:

```
    icon: { opacity: 0 }
```

to:

```
    icon: 'path/to/1x1.png'
```

One other error is in this code:

```
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    fillOpacity: 0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    strokeOpacity: 0.7,
    radius: 10000,
  });
```

That final comma at the end of the `radius` line shouldn't be there. It only affects older browsers like IE7, but if that comma is removed the map loads OK in IE7.

Also, with regard to using this:

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){...});
```

instead of this:

```
$(function(){...});
```

The reason that didn't make any difference is that they do the same thing!

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the tips. Although I did change the code using your var $position idea and I'm still getting the same error, so that wasn't it. I've edited my question to show the libraries I'm using, if that's any use.

Comment: Yeah, Christophe, it's the `icon: { opacity: 0 }` causing the problem.

Comment: BTW you have `&libraries=places` in your Maps API script URL, but you're not actually using the Places library in your code. If you won't be using it you can remove that. (It doesn't hurt anything for it to be there, just loads extra JS code.)

Comment: Michael, brilliant, removing that {opacity: 0} sorted out that error. But...the reason i had it there in the first place, I didn't want a marker on the user's lat, lng - so by setting opacity to 0, it was invisible. Now with that code gone, the marker is there. Any idea how to make it invisible, without using opacity? Thanks again. I'll also see if &libraries=places is used anywhere else in my project and, if not, take it out.

Comment: Download a copy of this file to your server: `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/1x1.png` and then use `icon: 'path/to/1x1.png'`.

Comment: Tried many places in my function to put that 'icon: 'path/to/1x1.png', but can't get it to work. I thought it would be in var myOptions ={zoom: zoom, icon: 'path/to/1x1.png', etc...is that the right place? Or maybe it's because I'm using Rails and my code is var myOptions = {zoom: zoom,
      icon:'<%= asset_path('1x1.png') %>', etc...etc..

Comment: The `icon` doesn't go in `myOptions`. Those are the options you're passing to the `new google.maps.Map()` constructor. You already had `icon:` in the right place in the `new google.maps.Marker()` call, where you had `icon:{opacity:0}` Just change it to use the PNG URL instead of `{opacity:0}`.

Comment: Ok, that was the first place I tried.could be my rails code-I'll play around with it.Thanks for everything!

Comment: Glad to help. Also I just noticed an error that breaks IE7 - see updated answer for details.