# 'offsetwidth' property can not be retrieved

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I encounter with the javascript error:

> JavaScript runtime error: undefined or null reference's 'offsetwidth' property can not be retrieved

Here is my javascript code block (myJavaScript.js):

```
function initializeMap() {

var lat = 41.4934579;
var lng = -90.50442090000001;
var myZoom = 14;

init(lat, lng, myZoom);

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
}

function init(lat, long, myZoom) {

var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
    zoom: myZoom
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    title: "ARA"
});

marker.setMap(map);
}
```

Here is my GoogleMaps.aspx:

```
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[KEY]&sensor=true">

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="myJavaScript.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        //Add onload to body
       // $(window).load(function () {
        //    initializeMap()
        //});
        initializeMap();           

    </script>
</head>
```

Some commentators says that I should check whether the document should loaded, so I uncomment the above, however I've got another error:

> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' undefined.

When I changed the my javascript code block (myJavaScript.js):

```
function initializeMap() {

var lat = 41.4934579;
var lng = -90.50442090000001;
var myZoom = 14;

function init() {

    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        zoom: myZoom
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        title: "ARA"
    });

    marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
}
```

Why shall I put everyting in one function in javascript file? Does not it destroy the readibility and maintainability?

Comment: Where is the elemment with id "map-canvas" in your HTML?

Comment: `JavaScript runtime error: '$' undefined.` is telling you that you need to include a jQuery script reference.

Comment: My suspicion is this is a duplicate of [Google MAP API Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740663/google-map-api-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-offsetwidth-of-null/11743096#11743096).  You are running the `initializeMap();` function in the head of your document.  Even if it exists in the body, the map-canvas element won't have been rendered at that point.

Comment: geocodezip, the "map-canvas" property is in the body section of the GoogleMaps.aspx. For keep it short, I did not write it in the post.

Comment: geocodezip, actually I have read the "Google MAP API Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null.". In the view of the map-canvas element shall be rendered prior to javascript manuplation, I have inserted the 
$(window).load(function () {
    initializeMap()
});
phrase, however I got the error "JavaScript runtime error: '$' undefined."