# Google maps not being displayed in django template

Tags: django, google-maps-api-3, django-templates

I am trying to display a google map for a django site. I have a template, roughly,

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
...
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%;height:400px;background-color:#CCC;"></div>
</div>
...
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
  }
</script>


{% endblock%}
```

When I reload the webpage, I can see that a request is being made for Google's map url's , but I see no map, just a plain gray background.

Answer (score 2):

i have the same problem in  html  code  I delete `<!DOCTYPE html>` and it work

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the line before closing your script tag:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

You can see it in the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple)

Comment: I've added it but I still don't get a map.

Comment: Have you check the javascript console of your browser to see if you have any errors? 
Your exemple with the line I have put work fine for me!

Comment: I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null main.js:39
ml main.js:39
Tl main.js:45
initialize`

Comment: You can find similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740663/google-map-api-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-offsetwidth-of-null). And I think you have to update the map creation with var `map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions );`