# Google Maps in Ruby on Rails JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

I am trying to create a Ruby on Rails application with Google Maps integration.

My source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Website</title>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function initialize() {

                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(56.794682, 25.224593);

                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: myLatlng
                }

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'This is a location'
                });
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            ready = function() { 

                //Current page ID
                var page_id = $('div.content').attr('id');

                //Navigation list of all pages
                var navigation_list = $("nav#navigation a");

                //Navigation list check
                navigation_list.each(function(a){

                    if ($(this).attr('id') == page_id) {

                        $(this).css("border-bottom", "3px solid #74c5bd");
                    }
                });
            }

            $(document).ready(ready)
            $(document).on('page:load', ready)

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <%= render "layouts/header" %>
        <%=yield %>
        <%= render "layouts/footer" %>

    </body>
</html>
```

Each time I load the screen I get a JavaScript error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'a.offsetWidth')
```

Also, the map is not displayed. When I reload the page, the map finally appears and the JavaScript error vanishes.

Where is the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: Where is your `div.content`?

Comment: `<%=yield %>` renders it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google MAP API Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740663/google-map-api-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-offsetwidth-of-null)

Comment: Tried the solution code. Doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

What I believe is happening in your case is turbolinks is reloading the `<body>`, but not the `<head>`. Your custom script is running, but the `google` object is null. That's why the error clears after a full page refresh when the head is reloaded.

**Without Turbolinks Quick Fix**

Make the link that points to your map opt out of turbolinks. This forces a full page refresh when the link is clicked.

```
<div id="some-div" data-no-turbolink>
  # Link to your Map Page
</div>
```

**With Turbolinks Fix**

Turbolinks is pretty cool. You can still use it with google maps, you just need to see if `google` is defined. This method will load google maps asynchronously if it is undefined, otherwise it will just run your `ready()` method.

```
var loadMap = function() {
  if (typeof google === 'undefined' ) {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&' + 'libraries=places&'+'callback=ready';
      document.body.appendChild(script);
  } else {
    ready();
  }
};
```

Then update the function call to:

```
$(document).ready(loadMap)
$(document).on('page:load', loadMap)
```

Comment: Take the map script out of the <head> and put it in the <body>. That should fix it, but consider putting your javascripts in the asset pipeline, as this is the standard practice.

Comment: Do you mean separate `script.js` file?