# Google Map Error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps, dom-events

I am working with Google map and I wrote a JS code like below and it works perfectly when a user gives location realizing permission by Browser, but when he blocks the permission, the map doesn't show anything and wen I click on its area I get the following error:\

## Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

## JS SCRIPT:

```
    var pos = new Object();
    var marker1 = new Object();
    var marker2 = new Object();
    var resp;
    var loc;
    var bus_loc;

    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            //        zoom: 13
        });

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
        var scope = angular.element($("#address")).scope();
        var angLoc;
        scope.$apply(function () {
            angLoc = scope.contact.business.location.split(',');
            bus_loc = {
                lat: parseFloat(angLoc[0]),
                lng: parseFloat(angLoc[1])
            };
        });
        var image = '/static/image/main_template/map/2.png';
        marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: bus_loc,
            icon: image
        });
        marker2.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.setPosition(bus_loc);
            infoWindow.setContent('<p style="padding: 0; margin-top: 10px; direction: rtl">ساینا</p>');
            infoWindow.open(map, marker2);
        });

        map.setCenter(bus_loc);
        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                pos = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };

                loc = {
                    lat: parseFloat(pos.lat),
                    lng: parseFloat(pos.lng)
                };
                var image = '/static/image/main_template/map/1.png';
                marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: loc,
                    icon: image
                });
                marker1.addListener('click', function() {
                    infoWindow.setPosition(loc);
                    infoWindow.setContent('<p style="padding: 0; margin-top: 10px; direction: rtl">اینجا هستید</p>');
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker1);
                });
                map.setCenter(loc);

                var distanceService = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
                distanceService.getDistanceMatrix({
                        origins: ['' + loc.lat + ',' + loc.lng + ''],
                        destinations: ['' + bus_loc.lat + ',' + bus_loc.lng + ''],
                        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                        durationInTraffic: true,
                        avoidHighways: false,
                        avoidTolls: false
                    },
                    function(response, status) {
                        if (status !== google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                            console.log('Error:', status);
                        } else {
                            resp = response;
                            $('#distance').html('<b>فاصله از شما: <b>' + resp.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text);
                            $('#duration').html('<b>زمان تخمینی رسیدن شما به این با خودرو: <b>' + resp.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text);

                        }
                    });



                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                bounds.extend(marker1.getPosition());
                bounds.extend(marker2.getPosition());

                map.fitBounds(bounds);


            }, function() {
                handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            });
        } else {
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
            handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }




    }

    function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        //    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        //    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
        //        'مکان جغرافیایی یافت نشد' :
        //        'مرورگر شما امکان نشان دادن مکان جغرافیایی را ندارد.');
    }
```

What should I do?

Comment: Line number of the error?

Comment: Normally no error, but when I click on the map area:
common.js:191 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Comment: My first idea: bus_loc should be a "new google.maps.LatLng", not just an object you make yourself with {lat: ..., lng: ...}

Comment: I userd "new google.maps.LatLng" no change!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not add any prototye inheritance to  like this , google maps rendering has problems with it

```
    Object.prototype.boolToArray = function () {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not overriding 'window.self'!

Had the same problem, when I put a break point where the error was thrown in common.js, I saw that it was checking window.self, and window.self did not = window!

My issue: I had created a component and wrote "self = this" instead of "var self = this".  I overwrote window.self which caused this error.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually due to the map div not being rendered before the javascript runs that needs to access it.
you can find answer to this [question  here in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740663/google-map-api-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-offsetwidth-of-null)

Comment: I put JS script at the bottom of body

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and in my case it was because the IE or the IIS Server blocks some google Maps URLs. You can check it using your developer tools <kbd>F12</kbd> in Network tab and load the page with and without permission. It's probable that you found a google Maps URL with status 4XX. 
I solved adding the google maps URLs to the trusted sites