# Heroku - Symfony2 - Angular - app with angular errors - .js not loading?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony, heroku

I just finished working on an app locally on my computer. It's a weird app, using a combination of Symfony2 and Angular. The app works fine locally, under developer and production mode. But when I upload to Heroku, I get a plethora of errors on the front end:

[image]

I will update this original question with any new content that may be needed to help answer this question. It seems maybe the scripts aren't being loaded or something? My .gitignore isn't holding back any folders that contain it, so it should be uploaded to heroku.

**Edit**

I'm looking at the loaded page content of the app (hosted on Heroku) and it appears that some scripts are being loaded, and others are not. I can click one script in the source, and I get a blank page, and another script (that has loaded) and it loads the script (.js).

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/35665196/5734037

and i think yes google maps has some issues with inheritance

Answer (score 0):

This one's easy. If you look at the responses for the requests you'll (probably) see you get the HTML for each file instead of the actual js/css file.

I'm assuming you're using `html5mode` too so this usually means your server (Nodejs) is not configured properly or you're missing `<base href="/">` in your index.

The proper way to configure NodeJS for `html5mode`:

```
//Look for statics first
var oneHour = 3600 * 1000;
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public'), {maxAge: oneHour}));
//If miss, check API routes - not mandatory of you don't have API
app.use(require('./routers/api'));
//Return the index for any other GET request
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: path.join(__dirname, '../public')});
});
```

The other case is you simply did not commit the js files to heroku so the file is non-existent and you're receiving the index as default.

Comment: This is gonna sound weird, but I'm not using Node.js. I'm using PHP Symfony2. It's an older app that scrapes web crap, and I must use php sadly. But yes, I am using html5 mode and I do have `<base href="/">` in my index.

Comment: You'll have to configure Symphony somewhat similar to what I purposed here. Check statics --> check api --> return index by default.

Comment: Okay, thanks, definitely a push in the right direction. I'll try to find something in Symfony that I can configure.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.slideshare.net/aperic/symfony2-and-angularjs slides 33 to 36. May point you in the right direction

Comment: I'm looking at the loaded page content of the app (hosted on Heroku) and it appears that some scripts are being loaded, and others are not. I can click one script in the source, and I get a blank page, and another script (that has loaded) and it loads the script (.js).

Comment: Did you commit the files to heroku?

Comment: Yes, via `git add .`, `git commit -am "update", and `git push heroku master`. I've double checked my .gitignore, and it's not preventing any necessary directories.