# Google Maps API custom icon marker won't display

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

New to coding so apologies in advance... am looking to add custom icon markers (multiple) to my map, but having trouble displaying even one (the map itself shows fine though).

What's wrong with my code as it stands? (below):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>TEST</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=TEST (I have a valid key here)" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 700px; height: 500px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 11,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.480782, -2.2445527),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 53.480782, lng: -2.2445527},
    title:"TEST",
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });

  marker.setMap(map);

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have an initialize function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an initialize function, so your  code executes before the DOM is rendered.  Look at the javascript console, you will see an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null`, if you search SO for that you will find that is due to the `<div id="map"></div>` not being rendered when the map code runs (related question: [Google MAP API Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740663/google-map-api-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-offsetwidth-of-null)).

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/92wak4x3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.480782, -2.2445527),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: 53.480782,
      lng: -2.2445527
    },
    title: "TEST",
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });

  marker.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Fantastic - had to do a bit of messing around due to my own noobishness but that sorted it - thanks alot!