# gmap error d is undefined

Tags: javascript, dictionary

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=...." ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gmaps.js"></script>
```

I'm using gmap.js and google api with key,
the page seem to load the map, but just at the end of loading it hides the map, in firefox console it's shows

> d is undefined

```
map = new GMaps({
        el: '#map',
        lat: 13.9972,
        lng: -89.5687,
        zoomControl : true,
        panControl : true,
        streetViewControl : false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        overviewMapControl: true
    });
```

PD: when I remove the key from the script api src then it works fine.

Comment: Check you have assigned the correct key. And if there are restrictions for the access key Ex: ip, domain rules. You can update this through https://console.developers.google.com/

Comment: As of 2018, removing the key doesn't work at all anymore. You have to get it right...

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem and it took me forever to find the solution but eventually I noticed that I was not passing the correct element to the `google.maps.Map()` function.

In my case, I just created a `<div id="map"></div>` object and searched for it with jQuery since I use that library. My code looked something like this:

```
jQuery("body").append("<div id='map'></div>")
...
var map_elem = jQuery("#map")
var map = new google.maps.Map(map_elem, { zoom: 4, center: lat_lng })
```

The fact is that I was passing the jQuery object instead of the DOM element. I had to use:

```
...(map_elem[0], ...
```

to get the first DOM element from the jQuery array.

In other words, if you don't pass the correct element to the `Map()` constructor, you are likely to get the error you mentioned here.

See also: [Google MAP API Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740663/google-map-api-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-offsetwidth-of-null)

Answer (score -1):

I've searched the web for you...
From what I found, your issue *may be related* to the setCenter() method that is missing in your code.

Try this:

```
center: {lat: 13.9972, lng: -89.5687}
```

Also check this page, which may be more specific to gmaps.js: https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/geolocation.html
There is a initMap() example which is different from your map definition.