# Google Maps is not displaying on an HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using GMaps to display a map on an html page but it gives this error on page

> Oops! Something went wrong.
>
> This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details.

And these errors in the console

EDIT: I've generated the API Key and added it to the URL and now I'm only getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

I have also checked this thread: [Google MAP API Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740663/google-map-api-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-offsetwidth-of-null)

And tried the snippets posted there instead of my own, but I got the same errors.

This is my code

HTML

```
<div id="map_canvas" class="height-400 grayscale"></div>
```

JS and Includes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDPN1LpoBuDzlvGox2qcREeDCnKu-hsGs4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/gmaps.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    /**
     @BASIC GOOGLE MAP
     **/
    var map2 = new GMaps({
        div: "#map_canvas",
        lat: -12.043333,
        lng: -77.028333,
        scrollwheel: false
    });

    var marker = map2.addMarker({
        lat: -12.043333,
        lng: -77.028333,
        title: "Company, Inc."
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Did you read the links it gave you in the console?

Comment: So you do not have an api key. Get an API key

Answer (score 2):

Try here to get an API key (Google account needed):

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/maps_backend/

For more information:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: I generated the API and used it in the URL, but im still getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined`

Comment: your code does not show the API key.. because the error is different, doesn't mean the previous problems are solved. Please update your code also.

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot the include it. Check it now. The API key is there.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're following the examples correctly, that your `gmaps.js` file is linked correctly, etc. I'm not sure where the prototype error would originate from, but I would recommended viewing the source of this page, and using it as your starting point: https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/basic.html

Comment: I am using exactly that. The error is coming from `http://maps.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/25/8/common.js`

Comment: Are you running this locally by dragging the file on to the browser? or on a web server? Can you link to your code?

Comment: I am running it locally inside XAMPP, I can provide you with the html code in a gist if you'd like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117742/discussion-between-halnex-and-toby).